# C# Numbers after decimal disappear after I join them with a string

Tags: c#

I have the following problem: After I add a string to my number the second digit after the point disappears like this

```
 var needed_product = sets * (2 * price_bananas) + 
                      sets * (4 * price_eggs) + 
                      sets * (0.2 * price_berries);

 var difference = Math.Abs(needed_product - amount_cash);

 if (amount_cash>=needed_product)
 {
    Console.Write("Ivancho has enough money - it would cost " + "{0:F2}", 
      needed_product + "lv."); 
 }
```

The output is 37,4 when it should be 37,40 with one more digit after the comma. How do I fix this problem?
When I print it without adding the last piece of string the output of the integer is correct.

Comment: Your code is fine "{0:F2}" will always output 2 decimal places. Are you sure you are running the correct build?

Comment: are you checking the value in the debugger or in the console?

Comment: In the console. "{0:F2}" doesn't output two decimal places when I join with +"lv.", only when I don't put anything after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incorrectly formatting your string. 
`Console.Write` takes a string argument, and then optionaly some arguments afterwards to pass into the string.

In your example code, your string is

```
"Ivancho has enough money - it would cost " + "{0:F2}"
```

and then the argument you pass into that string is

```
needed_product + "lv."
```

`needed_product` is added to "lv.", and in the process being converted into a string without your custom parameters. This means that `{0:F2}` is converted into a string and ignores the F2 modifier, giving

```
"Ivancho has enough money - it would cost 37.4 lv."
```

Instead, use

```
Console.Write("Ivancho has enough money - it would cost {0:F2} lv.", needed_product);
```

Comment: I actually cheated a bit because I posted my first sentence quickly, and then took the time to edit the message (you have 5 minutes to edit it before it's marked as edited). Anyway, your answer is good and detailed, welcome to StackOverflow and +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom format within a toString() call.

```
   double value = 37.4;
   Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: Why the **** is this downvoted, even though it's the correct answer? Here, have my upvote!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are concatenating the decimal value with a string, before it's being formatted.

In other words, your current code is functionally equivalent to:

```
var temp = needed_product + "lv."; // this gets formatted using default formatting
Console.Write("Ivancho has enough money - it would cost {0:F2}", temp);
```

To fix it, you should simply insert units into the actual format string:

```
Console.Write("Ivancho has enough money - it would cost {0:F2} lv", needed_product);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following, fixed code:

```
void Main()
{
    var sets=6;
    var price_bananas=0.88;
    var price_eggs=1.10;
    var price_berries=0.37;
    var amount_cash=40;
    var needed_product = sets * (2 * price_bananas) + sets * (4 * price_eggs) + sets * (0.2 * price_berries);
    var difference = Math.Abs(needed_product - amount_cash);
    if (amount_cash >= needed_product)
    {
        Console.Write(
        "Ivancho has enough money - it would cost " 
        + "{0:F2} lv.", needed_product); 
    }
}
```

It produces the correct output:

> Ivancho has enough money - it would cost 37,40 lv.

**Explanation:**
The other way you were trying first converts the number to a string internally (by using the equivalent of the `.ToString()` method), and then later applies the formatting `{0:F2}` which became useless because the number is already a string, formatted by default options.

To avoid this, build up the complete formatting string, then add the parameters without modification (as shown in the code).

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Good to hear, please mark it as answer if it is ok.  @MartinDimitrov

Answer (score 0):

You'll fix this problem by using integers and count cents. That's the only correct way to deal with currency.

Use a function that divide by 100 and format on each displayed output.

If you don't have problems right now using float, it will come sooner or later.

Comment: True, or the decimal datatype - which is easier to handle

Answer (score -2):

change this

```
"{0:F2}"
```

to

```
"{0:0.##}"
```

Comment: Changing "{0:F2}" to "{0:0.##}" does not work with Console.WriteLine();